# Button click in an list item should get me the textview text of that list item android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with multiple list items. Every item has a button which is working fine on click. But when i click on the button i want to extract the textview text in that respective list item. How can i do it? I am stuck please help.

Comment: Please provide the code you have already written, and show us what you have tried to solve the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ViewHolder, you can set a tag to your button that is the view holder. Then in the onClick, you retrieve the view holder, access the textView, and retrieve the text.

```
public static class ViewHolder() {
    public final TextView textView;
    public final Button button;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        // other stuff
        button.setTag(this);
    }
}
```

In your onClick:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (VIewHolder) view.getTag();
    String text = viewHolder.textView.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I am a beginner. So i really dont how the ViewHolder works. Can u please elaborate or is there any other way.

Comment: If the text in the textview is static, you could set the same text as a tag to the button. Then simply retrieve that tag in your onclick listener.